# VB.Net Inline comments

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, comments

Being a `c#` developer, I was very surprised to find i couldn't create `inline comments` within an `array` declaration.

In a test case I want to simulate 2 `byte array` packets coming through together:

```
Dim buffer As Byte() =
{
   &HF5,
   &H5,
   &H53,
   ... many more bytes
   &H1,
   &H2,
   &HCE, 
   &HF5, 'New packet starts here... this doesn't work :(
   &H5,
   &H53,
   ... many more bytes
   &H1,
   &H2,
   &H1A
}
```

Surely I'm missing something, is it possible to place inline comments within an array declaration?

If not, is there a decent work around? Probably need to split array into 2 and then join them together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't. But, you can use properly named variable. `Dim newPacketStarts As Byte = &HF5`. And use it inside declaration of the array. If you have a lot of hardcoded values, then create well named constants.

Comment: I see this feature was added in `Visual Basic 14` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Fabio, I think that's probably the best bet. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not possible.
But, as you found out by yourself, in the future version - Visual Basic 14 (Visual Studio 2015) this will be possible  [New Language Features in Visual Basic 14](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2014/12/09/new-language-features-in-visual-basic-14.aspx)

For current version you can create a properly named variable and use it in the array declaration

```vb
Dim newPacketStarts As Byte = &HF5
```

If you have a lot of hardcoded values - create constants with describable names

```vb
Const StartOfNewPacket As Byte = &HF5
Const AnotherValue As Byte = &H1
Const AnotherNewvalue As Byte = &HF53
'...
```

Declare array then

```vb
Dim buffer As Byte() = 
    {
        StartOfNewPacket,
        AnotherValue,
        AnotherNewvalue
    }
```

Comment: Ugh. *Finally*. We’ve been requesting this for almost 15 years now. *15 years*. Seeing this number written actually makes it seem unreal.